# Solidity, iterate over `mapping(address => unit256)`

Tags: for-loop, mapping, solidity

In solidity, I have a mapping of balances:

```
 mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
```

I need to go through each entry for each address (each key) of this mapping. Something like:

```
    for (address i = -1; i < maxAddress ; i++) {
        if (balances[i] > 0) {
            uint256 dividendOwing = _totalDividends.mul(balances[i]).div(totalTokens);
            _dividendBalances[i] = _dividendBalances[i].add(dividendOwing);
        }
    }
```

Obviously this is completely worthless as it will waste gas iterating through every possible address to a maxAddress. But I don't know of any way to accumulate addresses in an array like `address[]` from the above mapping.

In python, it would be as simple as `address[] = balances.keys()` or something like that.

I've also tried the following but found out it's not valid solidity:

```
function getAddresses() public view returns (address[] memory) {
    uint256 length = 0;
    for (address addr in balances) {
        length++;
    }
    address[] memory result = new address[](length);
    uint256 i = 0;
    for (address addr in balances) {
        result[i] = addr;
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

How do I iterate through this `balances` mapping to get to their individual address keys without brute forcing the address space?

Comment: is your first `for-lopp` valid soldiity code?

Answer (score 2):

Solidity mapping doesn't keep info about what keys have been set, which makes it not possible to iterate over.

On the other hand: If you know the key, it's more cost-effective to retrieve the value from a mapping than from an array.

If you want to retrieve list of valid keys, you'll need to store the keys in a separate array, and then iterate over the array. Example here: https://solidity-by-example.org/app/iterable-mapping/